# Upload Ogg File to audio streaming in Android

Tags: android, audio, shoutcast, icecast

I am noob in internet radio application. I am using `icecast` for this audio streaming so first here in my android application I captured the audio bytes in ogg file so I want to send this file for audio streaming.

My question How would I send this either complete *.ogg file or in some other format ?? Any help please

Here is my connect to icecast that is working

```
Socket s = new Socket("101.57.116.17", 8000);
Socket s = new Socket("101.57.116.17", 8000);
Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");
OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
Log.d("VS", "Output Stream Established");
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
Log.d("VS", "Send Header");
output.println("SOURCE /app ICE/2.3.3");
output.println("content-type: audio/mpeg");
output.println("Authorization: Basic c291cmNlOmhhY2ttZQ==");
output.println("ice-name: Server");
output.println("ice-genre: Rock");
output.println("ice-bitrate: 128");
output.println("ice-private: 0");
output.println("ice-public: 1");
output.println("ice-audio-info: ice-samplerate=44100;ice-bitrate=128;ice-channels=2");
output.println("");
output.flush();
Log.d("VS", "Header sent");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        s.getInputStream()));
String response = reader.readLine();
Log.v(LOG_TAG, response);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet httpGET = new HttpGet(
        "http://101.57.116.17:8000/admin/metadata?pass=hackme&mode=updinfo&mount=/app&song=akon");
httpGET.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic c291cmNlOmhhY2ttZQ==");
httpGET.setHeader("User-Agent", "(Mozilla Compatible)");

HttpResponse metaDataResponse = client.execute(httpGET);

System.out.println("Response Code : "
        + metaDataResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        metaDataResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have connected to the Icecast server and have been authorized, simply start sending your stream data down the same connection.

Note that you need to do this at the rate at which the playback occurs.  Otherwise, you will overrun a buffer and the audio for the client either won't work at all, or will skip around.

Comment: so I have OGG file so I need to read that file bytes in the code and send that bytes to server using same connection right ??